# Ruby Regexp trouble. How to accept a string only if it doesnt have 'foo'

Tags: ruby, regex

I need my regex to accept this:

```
"add chain=input comment="test" protocol=icmp blah blah other stuff"
```

but not accept this:

```
"add chain=input comment="test" blah blah disabled=yes
```

So basically if at the end of the string it says disabled=yes, don't match it.
I've tried this:

```
(add action=drop chain=input .*(?!disabled=yes))
add action=drop chain=input [^disabled=yes]
add action=drop chain=input.*[^(disabled=yes)]
```

and a couple other variations but to no avail. What am I doing incorrectly?

---

EDIT:

```
def check( line, key )
  return line[ key ] ? true : false
end

check( "add action=drop chain=input comment="test" disabled=yes", /add action=drop chain=input.*[^(disabled=yes)]/ )
```

This is some of the code, just broken down.

Comment: Show us the exact regex you're using, not just the string equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead based regex like below.

```
^(?!.*disabled=yes$)add(?: action=drop)? chain=input.*
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/tPAzWbhxjB)

`(?!.*disabled=yes$)` negative lookahead asserts that there isn't a string `disabled=yes` would be present at the last. And also i did make this `action=drop` string as optional because i didn't find this on your input string but on your regex.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a simple regex solution.

Answer (score -1):

Why use a regex?

```
[
  'add chain=input comment="test" protocol=icmp blah blah other stuff',
  'add chain=input comment="test" blah blah disabled=yes'
].reject{ |s| s.end_with?('disabled=yes') } # => ["add chain=input comment=\"test\" protocol=icmp blah blah other stuff"]
```

`end_with?` is about 2x faster than an equivalent regexp pattern.

```
require 'fruity'

compare do 
  _end_with { 'foo'.end_with?('o') }
  regexp { 'foo'[/o$/] }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _end_with is faster than regexp by 2x ± 0.1 (results differ: true vs o)
```

Normalizing the outputs to make them match only will slow using the pattern:

```
require 'fruity'

compare do 
  _end_with { 'foo'.end_with?('o') }
  regexp { !!'foo'[/o$/] }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _end_with is faster than regexp by 2.4x ± 0.1
```

If you just *HAVE* to use patterns, which is usually debatable, use a simple pattern to reject the strings you don't want first, so you're left with those you do:

```
[
  'add chain=input comment="test" protocol=icmp blah blah other stuff',
  'add chain=input comment="test" blah blah disabled=yes'
].reject{ |s| s[/disabled=yes$/] } # => ["add chain=input comment=\"test\" protocol=icmp blah blah other stuff"]
```

The more complex the pattern, the more likely something will go wrong and it'll spring leaks, resulting in false-positives. Instead, keep them very simple when possible.

If you *really* want to make it unreadable, add line-noise^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^^H^Ha use negative lookahead:

```
'blah blah other stuff'[/^((?!disabled=yes).)+$/] # => "blah blah other stuff"
'blah blah disabled=yes'[/^((?!disabled=yes).)+$/] # => nil
```

Comment: That would mean changing the check method. Which means altering a 100+ element array of regexps

Comment: Maybe, by showing a better example of what you're trying to do, we can help you avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: Is the regex that difficult to conjure?

Comment: We shouldn't have to conjure up what you've already written. Summarize what you've done so we can help you better. Otherwise, we can imagine a lot of things that are very far off the mark. See "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Help me better? I just need the regexp. I don't need to rewrite the whole program.